# using stored procedure in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add the following sproc to Entity Framework. After adding this via "Update from Model" the Model Browser shows this sproc in the "Function Imports" and "Stored Procedures/Functions" of the model. Using the "Edit" from Function Imports dialog I can not "Get Column Information" and unsuccessfully determine a Return type for the collection.

The output from the sproc is a temporary table but I do define the columns being returned. Is this sproc the problem? Am I missing a step in setting up the EF?

---

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addrApproxSP] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@frontage bigint = 0, 
@housedir varchar(1) = 0,
@streetnum bigint = 0, 
@streetdir varchar(1) = 0,
@distance bigint = 0
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Set Variables
DECLARE @lowfront bigint,
        @highfront bigint,
        @lowstreet bigint,
        @highstreet bigint,
        @currname varchar(25),
        @streetcur varchar(25),
        @whereclause varchar(40),
        @fixstreet varchar(25),
        @pos int,
        @piece varchar(500)

--Set variables to proper values in range
    Set @lowfront = @frontage - @distance
    set @highfront = @frontage + @distance
    set @lowstreet = @streetnum - @distance
    set @highstreet = @streetnum + @distance


-- Process for Street Names that are Numeric Values
-- Create Temp Table
CREATE TABLE #StreetNames
(streetname varchar(25))
-- SELECT StreetName and put in Temp table
INSERT #Streetnames(streetname)
select distinct streetname
from ADDR_STREETCOORD
where begincoord between @lowstreet and @highstreet
and STREETDIR = @streetdir
and lowhouse > @lowfront and HIGHHOUSE < @highfront
and HOUSEDIR = @housedir
union
select distinct streetname
from ADDR_STREETCOORD
where lowhouse > @lowstreet and HIGHHOUSE < @highstreet
and HOUSEDIR = @housedir
and begincoord between @lowfront and @highfront
and STREETDIR = @streetdir

-- Check each Streetname and those that are a coordinate (ex: "1000 S") change to "1000"
CREATE TABLE #FixStreets(streetname varchar(25))
DECLARE curStreet CURSOR FOR SELECT streetname FROM #StreetNames
    OPEN curStreet            
    FETCH NEXT FROM curStreet INTO @fixstreet  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN 
            --insert code here 
    INSERT #FixStreets(streetname)
        --Call Function to: parse the street name
        --if the first part isnumeric then insert that
        --if not numeric then keep as is
        select [dbo].fnParseCoordinate(@fixstreet)

        FETCH NEXT FROM curStreet INTO @fixstreet
    END 

CLOSE curStreet   
DEALLOCATE curStreet 

--select * from #FixStreets

--create a temp table to store the results of each street name in a single table
-- in order to return the results as a single table
--For Each street name search its frontage range values
--loop through each streetname to get the parcels matching those streets
CREATE TABLE #AllResults(Parcel varchar(14),Prop_locat varchar(50))
DECLARE curName CURSOR FOR SELECT streetname FROM #FixStreets
    OPEN curName            
    FETCH NEXT FROM curName INTO @streetcur  

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN 
            --insert code here 
    INSERT #AllResults(Parcel, Prop_locat)

        select  parcel_id,prop_locat
        from ADDR_ParcelsWWW
        where StreetName = @streetcur
        and predir = @housedir
        and housefrom between @lowfront and @highfront
        union
        select parcel_id,LOCATOR_ADDRESS
        from ADDR_MASTERADDRESS
        where StreetName = @streetcur
        and predir = @housedir
        and housefrom between @lowfront and @highfront

        FETCH NEXT FROM curName INTO @streetcur
    END 

CLOSE curName   
DEALLOCATE curName 

--Select the results of all the tables
select Parcel, prop_locat from #AllResults

END
```

---

Answer (score 0):

When EF polls your SP, it does this first: SET FMTONLY ON

This can screw things up if you use temp tables in your SP, which it looks like you're doing.

Try explicitly setting this at the beginning of your SP: SET FMTONLY OFF

That should allow EF to detect your columns.